# How to include xsl file with js script tags in another xsl?

Tags: javascript, html, xslt

I have xsl that I would like to include with another xsl that contains script tags of javascript files.

The Main xsl:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/Reflection">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>&lt;!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "SiteRef_getCSS?CSSName=Site/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"></xsl:text>
    <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="SiteRef_getCSS?CSSName=Site/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="SiteRef_getCSS?CSSName=Site/jquery.plupload.queue.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>

            <xsl:include href="CommonIncludes.xsl"/>

            <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="SiteRef_getJS?JSName=jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"/>-->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="SiteRef_getJS?JSName=jquery/jquery-ui.js"/>
        </head>
    </html>
```

CommonIncludes.xsl:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="SiteRef_getCSS?CSSName=Site/site.css" type="text/css"/>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="SiteRef_getJS?JSName=jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="SiteRef_getJS?JSName=Site/common.js"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="SiteRef_getJS?JSName=Site/MessagesConstants.js"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="SiteRef_getJS?JSName=Site/win_functions.js"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="SiteRef_getJS?JSName=Site/resizeFunctions.js"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

I got this exception: **javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Could not compile stylesheet**
Clearly, my CommonIncludes.xsl is not written correctly.
Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the `xsl:include` to the beginning of your stylesheet, before any templates. That would suffice to make the XSLT processor happy. But it would not call or apply the template in the included file to output the `link` and the `script` elements. To achieve that you could use

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:import href="CommonIncludes.xsl"/>
<xsl:template match="/Reflection">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>&lt;!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "SiteRef_getCSS?CSSName=Site/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"></xsl:text>
    <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="SiteRef_getCSS?CSSName=Site/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="SiteRef_getCSS?CSSName=Site/jquery.plupload.queue.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
            <xsl:apply-imports/>
```

I would however change the template match in the imported file to something more specialized like `<xsl:template match="/*">...</xsl:template>` or `<xsl:template match="/Reflection">..</xsl:template>`.

Or use a named template and call it where you want to include the elements.

And the `xsl:output` allows you to specify the document type and URL and have those output on serialization by the XSLT processor, there is no need to do that by hand.

Here are minimal but complete samples doing the `apply-imports` and the `xsl:import`:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:import href="test2014050802.xsl"/>

<xsl:template match="/Reflection">
    <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="SiteRef_getCSS?CSSName=Site/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="SiteRef_getCSS?CSSName=Site/jquery.plupload.queue.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
            <xsl:apply-imports/>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="SiteRef_getJS?JSName=jquery/jquery-ui.js"/>
        </head>
        <body>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>


<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="/Reflection">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="SiteRef_getCSS?CSSName=Site/site.css" type="text/css"/>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="SiteRef_getJS?JSName=jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="SiteRef_getJS?JSName=Site/common.js"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="SiteRef_getJS?JSName=Site/MessagesConstants.js"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="SiteRef_getJS?JSName=Site/win_functions.js"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="SiteRef_getJS?JSName=Site/resizeFunctions.js"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

When run against

```
<Reflection/>
```

I get the output

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="SiteRef_getCSS?CSSName=Site/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="SiteRef_getCSS?CSSName=Site/jquery.plupload.queue.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="SiteRef_getCSS?CSSName=Site/site.css" type="text/css"><script type="text/javascript" src="SiteRef_getJS?JSName=jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="SiteRef_getJS?JSName=Site/common.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="SiteRef_getJS?JSName=Site/MessagesConstants.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="SiteRef_getJS?JSName=Site/win_functions.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="SiteRef_getJS?JSName=Site/resizeFunctions.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="SiteRef_getJS?JSName=jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script></head>
   <body></body>
</html>
```

and no compilation error.

As for the `xsl:output`, let's solve that in another question if needed.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I did what you wrote here and still it fails in compilation error. Any ideas?

Comment: I also set name for the template Still doesn't work. Did you mean that after apply-imports to write the apply-template right? I didn't understand what you wrote about the xsl:output, how to use it...

Comment: @Snow, I have edited and provided two samples of XSLT that compile and outline the suggestions made.

Comment: Martin, thanks for the example. I think I found what is the problem, I need to implement URIResolver in my java server for handling 'include'/'import' xsl calls before transformation. Regardless, your code helped me very much.